# Which file properties do RAR store?

Tags: file-transfer, rar, winrar

Which file properties do RAR store?
Do they store the "Date Created" and if so, how can I extract the files while preserving it?
If not, are there other file formats that can do so?

Comment: Possibly useful link: [RAR 5.0 archive format](https://www.rarlab.com/technote.htm#timerecord). Note the document uses the name `ctime` for "creation time". In *nix `ctime` is "change time". "Date created" would be "birth time", `btime`. In many filesystems `btime` is not kept. From the document alone it's not immediately clear if `ctime` in RAR means `ctime` or `btime` in *nix. Anyway, even if RAR stores `btime`, extracting to a filesystem that doesn't support it obviously cannot preserve it. What is your OS? What filesystem do you want to extract to?

Comment: 7Zip preserves original timestamps. I consider Winrar obsolete because it's weaker at compression and it's not free. So I'd switch to 7Z. The problem in a case such as yours with WinRAR is that the OS may decide to write the date as the unarch date rather than the original files date.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Just from Windows 10 to Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using WinRAR, you can set some time parameters and they will be kept on the rar archive as stated [here](https://documentation.help/WinRAR/HELPExtractAdvOptions.htm):

> Windows file systems keep three different time fields for each file: last modification, creation and last access. By default WinRAR stores only last modification time, but using file time options in Time part of archiving dialog you may enable storing of creation and last access time. Even if a desired time field is present in archive, it is also necessary to set the corresponding time option in the extraction dialog to restore it on extraction. All these options are supported only by RAR and ZIP archives, for other formats WinRAR always restores only the modification time.

You have to set the parameter when you create the archive. When restoring the files, they will be restored with the creation time, last access time, etc.

[image: IMG:]